# Can i make extern variable const?

Tags: c++

I have a global variable which i want to share in the whole project.

```
// A.h
int a;
```

But i only write it in one place, and other place only need to read.

```
// B.h : only place can modify a
extern int a;
void mod(int b) {
  a = b;
}

// C.h: only read
extern int a;  // extern const int a doest work
void show() {
  printf("%d", a);
}
```

Can i `extern` it in other place with `const`?

I tried in my code, but seems not work.

Can you give me some suggestions? is there any other method to achieve this if `extern` doest work?

Comment: You should be if you also do the same in the header file. But to be honest if you want to share data between files there are better ways (Meyer's singleton, or even better dependency injection)

Comment: All your files are named `.h`.  Are you doing a single-compilation-unit build where all the code gets included into one source file?  Do proposed answers have to work like that too, or are you open to a solution with multiple compilation units (i.e. multiple `.cpp` files)?

Comment: Note that any translation unit that includes `A.h` will end up with its own copy of `a`, breaking the `extern`s. `a` should be declared `extern` in `A.h` too, and then `int a;` declared in `a` .cpp file instead.

Comment: Have you considered perhaps not using an extern global variable at all but instead a free function that simply returns the value of `a`, which would be in a single compilation unit (.cpp file)?

Comment: Your problem is that you declared the variable in the header, but in your case, you have a logical error. It is not really const. Declaring something as const means allowing the compiler to optimize out reads. Here is the point: your variable can change. You cannot not read it and just assume it didn't change. It could have changed externally, but changed. It is not const.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: Yes, `extern const` is possible to use in a declaration. The downside, of course, is that then you cannot change it anywhere. So `const` in one place and non-`const` in another place? Nope!